# How does it really feel when people say "thank you for your patience" to their clients in English?

Tags: meaning, idioms, politeness

Yesterday I invited a client twice.

For the first appointment I made, the client met with me but we could not complete our task due to lack of preparation. So the client left and I made the second appointment with thorough preparation. In the end the client came for the second time and we got things done successfully.

My client was still nice to people, as always.

I think my client has been patient with this situation.

But I know I should not make the same mistake again.

I found a webpage which says
[Thank You For Your Patience: Avoid Saying This To Clients](https://yoursalesmaven.com/blog/avoid-saying-this-to-clients-thank-you-for-your-patience/)

1

> So how does it really feel when people say "thank you for your patience" to their clients in English?

and

2

> What should I say after this experience?

Comment: What does 'invited them twice' mean? Do you mean that you accidentally gave them two different appointments when they only wanted one? I think the point is that you shouldn't automatically say it when something goes wrong, because you would seem to be taking their patience for granted.

Comment: The web page says you should not 'thank' people for patience that has not been freely given, or before the person has had a chance to freely give it. It says that you should not request clients to be patient. If your client showed patience without being asked to, then it was appropriate to thank him or her.

Comment: Generally, assuming there is a valid reason to do so, e.g. if your client has expressed some understanding reagrding a delay, then there is absolutely nothing wrong with saying"thank you for your patience". It's a fairly common polite expression. It also acknowledges that there has been a problem and I think most people would appreciate it being said. I find some of these websites that make such suggestions to be quite bizarre TBH.

Comment: @BillyKerr - that website seems to be giving advice to sales people, and a pop-up advertises the author's book on the same subject. Sales people are not always concerned about etiquette, which is what this question is really about.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "Sales people are not always concerned about etiquette" - that's very true!  It could even be seen as sarcastic, condescending, or dismissive of a delay if said in the wrong context, but that's not generally the normal use of this phrase. I think it has given the OP the wrong impression, that it should never be said.

Comment: @BillyKerr - many people find 'thanks in advance' to be irritating, and see the phrase, or others with the same message, as annoying attempts at persuasion. It can have the opposite effect to that intended.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I agree. In such cases I think a direct apology would be better "Sorry for the delay", "I apologise for the delay in getting back to you", etc.

Comment: @BillyKerr - yes, absolutely. If you have to tell the client that there is going to be an unavoidable delay, it doesn't really matter how you say it. There are a number of stock things to say. You can thank them for their patience, understanding, etc, afterwards, when the service has been sucessfully provided. If they have expressed anger or impatience, thanking them for some non-existent 'patience' could be seen as passive-aggressive rudeness.

Comment: @KateBunting
For the first appointment I made the client met with me but we cannot complete our task due to lack of preparation.
So the client left and I made the second appointment with thorough preparation.
In the end the client came for the second time and we get things done succesfully.

Comment: I've edited your explanation into the original question.

Comment: @KateBunting
Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: This is a matter for [ips.se].  There is no English error in saying "Thank you for your patience" but it might not be appropriate, as described on your link.

Comment: I've closed this as it cannot be answered with citations, only personal opinion. As James K has said, it could be asked in Interpersonal Skills. It would also be appropriate for [workplace.SE].

Comment: Appreciate this discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, "thank you for your patience" is perfectly appropriate *when the wait comes to an end:* a restaurant patron has been waiting for a table, so you thank them for their patience and seat them. This applies whether they really have been waiting a frustrating amount of time or just a little longer than usual, though of course in the former case you'll emphasize it more.

Saying it to someone who's still waiting is shakier. Like many stock customer service phrases, it can be neutral as long as it's not overused, and it serves a purpose: a perfunctory acknowledgement that you're growing impatient is better than no acknowledgement. As the article you linked suggests, there are alternatives that can make the customer feel more in control, but the bottom line is that being kept waiting is never pleasant, you have to say *something*, and what you say is usually less important than how you say it (and what you do about it).

Comment: Yes. A stock phrase. I won't 'feel' much different whether someone says 'Thank you for your patience while I consult the database/call my manager/whatever' or if they say 'Please bear with me while I...' or 'I'm sorry but I have to...' It's a routine everyday situation and for most people it doesn't really matter what you say, as long as it isn't actually rude. People from very deferential societies may overthink this type of thing when considering how to manage such a situation in English.